# Plotting separate charts for columns below each merged cell dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, charts, multiple-columns

What changes should I make in the ranges of the code below so that the code will search for each unique merged cell, and and plot the chart of the columns below that merged cell for particular department. I can have dynamic number of columns below different merged cells (like for different number of months). Also, the number of departments will be dynamic. All suggest other changes in the code for this. (I have used 'ColumnMax' in the code as it will be used for long ranges, and will be used in place of '7')

Kindly find my data here with the sample chart http://bit.ly/1dROvFs . I want the code to plot the same type of charts for all the departments dynamically.

Code is as following:

```
Sub Charts()
Dim rChart1 As Range
Dim iColumn As Long
Dim lastCol4 As Long
Dim currentrcol As Long
Dim cht1 As Chart

lastCol4 = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Const StrtRow As Long = 1
Const EndRow As Long = 7
Dim ColumnMax As Long
ColumnMax = lastCol4 - 4

With ActiveSheet

Set rChart1 = .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, "A"), .Cells(EndRow, "A"))

For iColumn = 2 To 7 Step 2
Set rChart1 = Union(rChart1, .Range(.Cells(StrtRow, iColumn), .Cells(EndRow, iColumn)))
Next

Set cht1 = .Shapes.AddChart.Chart

With cht1
  .Parent.Left = .Parent.Left - .Parent.Width / 2
  .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
  .SetSourceData rChart1, xlColumns

End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.